# Git branch with rebase

Tags: git, github, git-branch

This is what I usually do at my work:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
git commit -m 'fixed something #8852'
git rebase -i master
git push origin my_branch
```

Then after some time I needed to work again on the same branch. Since then new commits appeared on master branch. I checked out my branch, made changes, commited and did 'git rebase -i master'. But when I tried to do 'git push origin my_branch' it gave me an error:

```
! [rejected]        my_branch -> my_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXX.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

My master was up to date. So from my_branch I did

```
git pull --rebase origin my_branch
git push origin my_branch
```

I think it rebased all new commits to my branch. Now on my_branch I have commits that don't belong to it. Note: my team leader asked me to do always rebase to avoid merging. How I should've solved this error so my_branch would contain only my commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is saying is that your remote branch is more advanced (in the tree) than your local branch. This tends to happen when you are collaborating and rebasing. It is recommended that if your are following a methodology that you need to collaborate with other people branch you should merge. If you do a quick google search you will find lots of good git tutorials that can help you get better with this!

Now, for fixing your problem there are few solutions. What I think is the best one will be:

- `git log` and write down the hashes for the commits you want to have (you can copy and paste them somewhere)
- Go to a safe starting point and create a new branch (`git checkout -b branch_name`)
- Cherry-pick the commits you want to have to your new branch (`git cherry-pick commit-hash`), if they are a lot of commits you could do a interactive rebase with your old branch and just choose the commits you want.
- Be happy with your new branch that have all the info you want to have and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

When you are on master, and you do `git checkout -b my_branch` you are up to date at that moment.

Later, after some work on your branch, you will want to update those things from master, so you do a `git pull master`  This is OK.

Once you are good and everything is working, then you would normally have the code review process happen, and approval on that.

The manager can be on master and do a `git rebase my_branch` if that is the policy.

So, the problem presents itself in rebasing and reordering the history in both directions.